# Problem with downloading libraries in thonny micropython

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, thonny

I cant install libraries in micropython for my Raspberry Pi Pico W

I was using the mip. and i get this(I was trying to download picozero):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "mip/__init__.py", line 1, in install
  File "mip/__init__.py", line 1, in _install_package
  File "mip/__init__.py", line 1, in _install_json
  File "urequests.py", line 180, in get
  File "urequests.py", line 76, in request
OSError: -6
```

Comment: How are you using mip? `import mip` from the REPL prompt or `mpremote mip install` from your PC? If it's `import mip` from the REPL, you need to connect to WiFi first.

Comment: I am using import mip and I am connnected to the WiFi

Comment: and when I am using the "manage packages" I have this error:
Successfully installed picozero-0.4.2
Starting to apply changes to the target.
Copying picozeroError (ManagementError(...), 'Command output was not empty')